# Converting a type to an array - GO syntax

Tags: go

In the below syntax_1,

```
 array := [...]float64{7.0, 8.5, 9.1}
```

and syntax_2,

```
type People interface {
    SayHello()
    ToString()
}

type Student struct {
    Person
    university string
    course string
}

type Developer struct {
    Person
    company string
    platform string
}


func main(){

    alex := Student{Person{"alex", 21, "111-222-XXX"}, "MIT","BS CS"}
    john := Developer{Person{"John", 35, "111-222-XXX"}, "Accel North America", "Golang"}
    jithesh := Developer{Person{"Jithesh", 33, "111-222-XXX"}, "Accel North America", "Hadoop"}
    //An array with People types    
    peopleArr := [...]People{alex, john,jithesh}
}
```

---

1) What does this syntax `float64{7.0, 8.5, 9.1}` & `People{alex, john,jithesh}` mean? this looks like a paradigm(a way of programming) more than a syntax

2) Can you provide reference to the meaning/purpose of `[...]` syntax? I see converting something to an `[]` type

Comment: It's all here: https://golang.org/ref/spec. 1) A *composite literal*, it is syntax, not "paradigm". 2) Create an array whose length is the same as the number of elements provided to the literal.

Comment: @mkopriva https://golang.org/search?q=%5B...%5D

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), and _"The notation `...` specifies an array length equal to the maximum element index plus one."_

Comment: @overexchange what are you implying with that link? That it's hard to find? Try the link in my first comment and try searching that page with CTRL/CMD+F, that's more efficient.

Comment: Important to note that `People{alex, john,jithesh}` is much different than `[...]People{alex, john,jithesh}`.   The latter creating an array of objects that implement the People interface.

Comment: @mkopriva syntax_1 came from CTRL/CMD+F.

Comment: @Devon (Array of objects) implementing `People` interface or Array of (object)s implementing `People` interface?

Comment: Unnamed arrays* can't implement interfaces.  It's objects that implement interfaces, so you have an array of objects and those objects implement the interface.  Edit:  I use objects here, but it may be more correct to say structs.

Comment: @overexchange If you read the whole section on composite literals which icza linked to you'll find explanation for both 1) and 2).  The paragraph explaining `[...]` is a bit furhter down but it is there. Do CTRL/CMD+F for the string `The length of an array literal` and you'll see it.

Comment: @Doven  Before composing the literals(objects) as `People{alex, john, jithesh}`, does each literal(object say `alex`) suppose to implement `People` interface? same with `float64{1.0, 2.0}`

Comment: @overexchange: yes, naturally. Or else you'll get compilation error. It's called static typing.

Answer (score 0):

Squiggly brackets are used to define a composite literal. A value that contains more than one value inside it. In your first example an array of float values is created
`[...]float64{7.0, 8.5, 9.1}` is a literal for an array of floats with 3 elements. In your second example, a few literals for predefined struct types are created and another array. `Person{"alex", 21, "111-222-XXX"}` is a literal for a struct of type Person. And `[...]People{alex, john,jithesh}` is an array of type People containing 3 elements.

Comment: Can I say , `People{alex, john, jitesh}` is a composite literal for a struct of type `People`? where name `alex` is pointing to a literal(object) for a struct of type `Student`?

Comment: People type is an interface, so anything that implements this interface can be a member of this array. For this code to work both Developer and Student need to implement People interface either directly or through the embedded Person struct.

Comment: But `People{alex, john, jitesh}` on its own is not valid. It needs `[...]` to make it an array of People. Or simply `[]` to make it a slice of People.

Comment: `[...]People{}` is an array. `[]People{}` is a slice. These are two different types.

Comment: `[...]People{}` would create an empty array of zero elements, but `[...]People{alex, john, jitesh}` would create a populated array of three elements